# Is there a list of column references that will break query functions in Google Sheets? (column BY, OR)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, reserved-words

I am using column references in a Google Sheets query and realized that column BY (Col #77) breaks my query, as BY is a special word in querying. The solution is to enclose BY in quotations (`BY`) within the query. Today I realized that OR (Col #408) was breaking my query as well. Is there a way I can identify what these words are ahead of time? I'm guessing column AND is also problematic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

see: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Reserved_Words

so, as per documentation, you will need to backquote only these 5:

```
`BY`
`OR`
`AND`
`ASC`
`NOT`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, enclose the area with curly brackets and use ColX.

Example, replace `=query(A:BY,"select A, BY")` by `=query({A:BY},"select Col1, Col77")`

Note that x is not an absolute value but relative to the virtual matrix, i.e. `=query({BX:BX,BY:BY,OR:OR},"select Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null")`

Answer (score 0):

[Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71487060/12306687) is a great workaround to this but if you're still looking for a list you can refer to the [Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273) and their [Query Language Reserved Words](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#reserved-words) reference, so you can have an idea of what words are reserved in Sheets.